# ydn-db fulltext species search demo doesn't work when offline: this.db.search is not a function

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, ydn-db

I opened http://dev.yathit.com/demo/ydn-db-text/animals/animals.html demo online, it worked. But when I try to use this demo in an offline mode, something goes wrong.

These error messages appear right after I type something into input:

Chrome (with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag enabled):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'search'  -->  animals.js:111
  Animals.handleSearch
```

Firefox:

```
TypeError: this.db.search is not a function
  var rq = this.db.search('name', this.ele_input_.value);
  animals.js (line 111)
```

By the way, I have "2359 animals loaded, indexing... done." message, it means that database is loaded, but what's the problem with `var rq = this.db.search('name', this.ele_input_.value)`?

**UPDATE**
I checked https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db-fulltext/blob/master/examples/animals/animals.html source, and now I see the problem: two local js files (`ydn-db.js` and `animals.js`) are not enough, this app has a lot of dependencies:

```
<script src="../../../closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
<script src="../../../closure-library/closure/goog/deps.js"></script>
<script src="../../../ydn-base/src/deps.js"></script>
<script src="../../../ydn-db/src/deps.js"></script>
<script src="../../../natural/js/deps.js"></script>
<script src="../../../fullproof/js/deps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="../../../fullproof/js/tokenizer/categ_letters_numbers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="../../../fullproof/js/tokenizer/normalizer_lowercase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="../../../fullproof/js/tokenizer/normalizer_lowercase_nomark.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/deps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    goog.require('ydn.debug');
    goog.require('ydn.db.crud.Storage');
    goog.require('ydn.db.crud.Storage.text');
</script>
<script src="../../../ydn-db/config/crud.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../ydn-db/src/ydn/db/tr/inject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../ydn-db/src/ydn/db/crud/inject.js"></script>
```

but those files are not included in the downloadable zip package.

Comment: After compiled, you don't need these dependency.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using different ydn-db js file. Most of the ydn-db distribution files do not have full text search module.

The web page is client side html. It should work. IndexedDB must served by a valid origin, so spin up server for testing. `--allow-file-access-from-files` is irrelevant I believe.

Did you use the js file in the demo?

Comment: you can check the update. By the way, `allow-file-access-from-files` is not irrelevant. If you don't set this flag, you get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///path/to/data.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP` error, because database is loaded by AJAX! But can you provide the full list of urls to required js files? (because they are not included in the downloadable github zip package)

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding. This web page will not run with `file` protocol.

Comment: but can you explain why? If this app has no server-side dependency (only client-side code), then what's thr problem with `file://` protocol???

Comment: @lyricallywicked - That's just the way browsers work. The file protocol is just limited. You need a webserver, even if it's local, just so you're using the http protocol. This isn't a problem with ydb... it's just how the browsers are built.